# LUA - LÖVE 2D - Sprite dying when hitting a box

Tags: lua, 2d, coordinates, love2d

--Okay, basically I've set up pretty much everything i want in the game. All i have to do now is create the enemies. I've set up the spawning and movement but when the player hits the enemies, nothing happens. When the red ball hits the blocks i'd like the client to close. (i will obviously change this at a later date but its only temporary) I'd be very grateful if you could program the code that would interpret this within the game. I'm new to this programming language and I'm only 15 still learning how to code. I am more than happy to give you credit in the game.

Thank you - Olee

```
function love.load()
    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( 110, 110, 110 ) --Sets background colour
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",400,300,0,230,230) --Draws game background
    print("Olee's Game") -- prints into the console
    x=140 --x position of sprite
    y=320 --y position of the sprite
    swidth=20 --sprite width
    sheight=20 --sprite height
    evil=900 --red rectangular blocks x position
    evilheight=64 --red rectangular block height
    evilwidth=256 --red rectangular block width
    points=0 --point system created variable
    random1y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the first enemy block
    random2y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random3y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random4y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random5y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random6y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
end

function love.update(dt)
    --BOUNDRIES--(makes the sprite not go off the page)
    if y<120 then
        y=y+20
    end
    if y>520 then
        y=y-20
    end
    if x<20 then
        x=x+20
    end
    if x>780 then
        x=x-20
    end

    --AI (sends the blocks back to the start)
    evil=evil-400*dt 
    if evil<=(-400) then
        evil=1100
        random1y=math.random(120,480)
        random2y=math.random(120,480)
        random3y=math.random(120,480)
        random4y=math.random(120,480)
        random5y=math.random(120,480)
        random6y=math.random(120,480)
    end

    --Points
    points = love.timer.getTime()
    points=math.floor(points)
end

function love.focus(bool)
end

function love.keypressed( key, unicode )
    print("You just pressed "..key)
    print("x="..x.."\ny="..y.."\n#########")
    if key=="escape"then
        print("Bye!")
        os.exit(0)
    end

    if key == "down" then
        y=y+20
    end

    if key == "left" then --A KEY (LEFT)
        x=x-20
    end

    if key == "right" then --D KEY (RIGHT)
        x=x+20
    end

    if key == "up" then --W KEY (UP)
        y=y-20
    end
end

function love.draw()
    --Floor
    love.graphics.setColor(127, 127, 127)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",0,540,5000,100)
    --Ceiling
    love.graphics.setColor(127, 127, 127)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 0, 0, 5000, 100)

    --Welcome Message
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.print("Bonjourno and Welcome to Olee's Game",32,32,0,1,1)

    --Welcome Message HUD Box
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("line",16,18,284,48)

    --Circle (sprite)
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.circle("fill",x,y,swidth,sheight)

    --SCOREBOARD
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.print("Score: "..points.."",620, 35)

    --Evil 1
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random1y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 2
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random2y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 3
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random3y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 4
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random4y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 5 
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random5y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 6
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random6y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --FPS
    love.graphics.print("FPS: "..tostring(love.timer.getFPS( )), 735, 5)
end

function love.quit()
end
```

Just to let you guys know, I HAVE set up a conf.lua file. My game works perfectly but i would like to add this! :)

and i have a play.bat

conf.lua:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.modules.joystick = true   -- Enable the joystick module (boolean)
    t.modules.audio = true      -- Enable the audio module (boolean)
    t.modules.keyboard = true   -- Enable the keyboard module (boolean)
    t.modules.event = true      -- Enable the event module (boolean)
    t.modules.image = true      -- Enable the image module (boolean)
    t.modules.graphics = true   -- Enable the graphics module (boolean)
    t.modules.timer = true      -- Enable the timer module (boolean)
    t.modules.mouse = true      -- Enable the mouse module (boolean)
    t.modules.sound = true      -- Enable the sound module (boolean)
    t.modules.timer = true      -- Enable the timer module (boolean)
    t.modules.thread = true
    t.modules.math = true       -- Enable the math module (boolean)
    t.modules.physics = true    -- Enable the physics module (boolean)
    t.console = true            -- Attach a console (boolean, Windows only)
    t.title = "Olee's Game"     -- The title of the window the game is in (string)
    t.author = "Olee"           -- The author of the game (string)
    t.screen.fullscreen = false -- Enable fullscreen (boolean)
    t.screen.vsync = false      -- Enable vertical sync (boolean)
    t.screen.fsaa = 0           -- The number of FSAA-buffers (number)
    t.screen.height = 600       -- The window height (number)
    t.screen.width = 800        -- The window width (number)
end
```

play.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOVE\love.exe" .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two approaches here:

1. *You can do advanced collision*
2. *You can do simple collision.*

The second is simpler, but the first is much better for this sort of game.

1. *First approach:*

First, you need to know this code:

```
function circleAndRectangleOverlap( circleX, circleY, circleRadius, rectangleX, rectangleY, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight )
    local distanceX = math.abs( circleX - rectangleX - rectangleWidth / 2 )
    local distanceY = math.abs( circleY - rectangleY - rectangleHeight / 2 )

    if distanceX > ( rectangleWidth / 2 + circleRadius ) or distanceY > ( rectangleHeight  /2 + circleRadius ) then
        return false
    elseif distanceX <= ( rectangleWidth / 2 ) or distanceY <= ( rectangleHeight / 2 ) then
        return true
    end

    return ( math.pow( distanceX - rectangleWidth / 2, 2 ) + math.pow( distanceY - rectangleHeight / 2, 2 ) ) <= math.pow( circleRadius, 2 )
end
```

Then you can add this to the rest of this code.

```
function love.load()
    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( 110, 110, 110 ) --Sets background colour
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",400,300,0,230,230) --Draws game background
    print("Olee's Game") -- prints into the console
    x=140 --x position of sprite
    y=320 --y position of the sprite
    sradius=20 --sprite radius
    evil=900 --red rectangular blocks x position
    evilheight=64 --red rectangular block height
    evilwidth=256 --red rectangular block width
    points=0 --point system created variable
    random1y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the first enemy block
    random2y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random3y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random4y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random5y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
    random6y=math.random(120,480) --creates y position of the block
end

function love.update(dt)
    --BOUNDRIES--(makes the sprite not go off the page)
    if y<120 then
        y=y+20
    end
    if y>520 then
        y=y-20
    end
    if x<20 then
        x=x+20
    end
    if x>780 then
        x=x-20
    end

    --AI (sends the blocks back to the start)
    evil=evil-400*dt 
    if evil<=(-400) then
        evil=1100
        random1y=math.random(120,480)
        random2y=math.random(120,480)
        random3y=math.random(120,480)
        random4y=math.random(120,480)
        random5y=math.random(120,480)
        random6y=math.random(120,480)
    end

    --Points
    points = love.timer.getTime()
    points=math.floor(points)

    -- Check collisions
    if circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random1y, evilwidth, evilheight ) 
    or circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random2y, evilwidth, evilheight )
    or circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random3y, evilwidth, evilheight )
    or circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random4y, evilwidth, evilheight )
    or circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random5y, evilwidth, evilheight )
    or circleAndRectangleOverlap( x, y, sradius, evil, random6y, evilwidth, evilheight ) then
        love.event.quit()
    end
end

function love.focus(bool)
end

function love.keypressed( key, unicode )
    print("You just pressed "..key)
    print("x="..x.."\ny="..y.."\n#########")
    if key=="escape"then
        print("Bye!")
        love.event.quit()
    end

    if key == "down" then
        y=y+20
    end

    if key == "left" then --A KEY (LEFT)
        x=x-20
    end

    if key == "right" then --D KEY (RIGHT)
        x=x+20
    end

    if key == "up" then --W KEY (UP)
        y=y-20
    end
end

function love.draw()
    --Floor
    love.graphics.setColor(127, 127, 127)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",0,540,5000,100)
    --Ceiling
    love.graphics.setColor(127, 127, 127)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 0, 0, 5000, 100)

    --Welcome Message
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.print("Bonjourno and Welcome to Olee's Game",32,32,0,1,1)

    --Welcome Message HUD Box
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("line",16,18,284,48)

    --Circle (sprite)
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.circle("fill",x,y,sradius)

    --SCOREBOARD
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.print("Score: "..points.."",620, 35)

    --Evil 1
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random1y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 2
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random2y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 3
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random3y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 4
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random4y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 5 
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random5y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --Evil 6
    love.graphics.setColor(191, 0, 52)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",evil,random6y,evilwidth,evilheight)

    --FPS
    love.graphics.print("FPS: "..tostring(love.timer.getFPS( )), 735, 5)
end

function love.quit()
end
```

2. *Second Approach*

This uses the AABB aproach, which will be more useful if you use actual sprites in the future.
Just plug this in for the `circleAndRectangleOverlap` with this (and width and height arguments instead of radius):

```
function checkAABB( spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, rectangleX, rectangleY, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight )
    if ( ( spriteX >= rectangleX + rectangleWidth)
    or ( spriteX + spriteWidth <= rectangleX ) 
    or ( spriteY >= rectangleY + rectangleHeight ) 
    or ( spriteY + spriteHeight <= rectangleY ) ) then
       return false 
   else return true
       end
   end
end
```